# Send auto-generated password” check-box does nothing?

Tags: email, magento, passwords, admin, magento-1.7

The “Send auto-generated password” check-box in admin does nothing? It doesn't send the  auto-generated password via email to the customer!

How to make it work?(I'm using Magento v1.7)

Comment: It seems that you have problems with email server. Where have you tested?

Comment: @Serjio, Thanks for your help! There are something wrong on my email server. I have post on [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558156/magento-how-to-make-smtp-server-working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558156/magento-how-to-make-smtp-server-working)