# Magento - How enable SMTP server authentication and secure transport?

Tags: magento, email, smtp

I'd like to make the SMTP server working on Magento app(version 1.7). so I added the following code on file `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php`

```
public function getMail()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_mail)) {

            /*Start of added code to specify config*/
            $my_smtp_host = Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/host');
            $my_smtp_port = Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/port'); 

            $config = array(
                    'ssl' => 'tls',
                    'port' => $my_smtp_port,
                    'auth' => 'login',
                    'username' => 'account@gmail.com',
                    'password' => 'secret'
            );

            $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp($my_smtp_host, $config);

            Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($transport);
            /*End of added code to specify config*/

            $this->_mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');
        }
        return $this->_mail;
    }
```

Then on **Admin Panel->System->Configuration->Advanced->System->Mail sending settings**

The following settings have been added

- Host:  smtp.gmail.com
- Port(25): 587

After completing these changes, I did test (i.e. Email to a Friend )on frontend. The success message was shown but the email wasn't in the mailbox(Not even in the spam).

Hope anyone can help me. Really appreciate,Thanks!

Comment: did you test on localhost? If it's true so nothing strange that the email was gone to spam folder

Comment: Wrong function being overwritten, `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template -> send()` is what needs to be overwritten with your module code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not hack into the core code, there are many reasons because this it NOT a good idea. One is: You aren't able to upgrade.

Instead use a extension or write your own:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ASchroder/extension/1865/aschroder.com-smtp-pro

Comment: have you tried it? If yes, you have to implement your own module. Maybe contact @aschroeder on Twitter and ask for an update. If you need help, contact me: stackoverflow@fabian-blechschmidt.de

Comment: @DHC I overwrote your comment, sorry.

Comment: Fabian, do you happen to know if this extension is on github?  I wanted to have a quick peek at some of the code for this without having to download the whole thing through magento connect?  Lazy :)

Comment: No Idea, I asked him via Twitter, will post the answer here, BUT you can download it via pear, somehow and aschroder knows the answer, awsome guy :) http://www.aschroder.com/2011/01/downloading-a-magento-connect-extension-manually-before-installing-it/ Or you use this tool: http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php

Comment: I need a extension for 1.7.0 :(

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt Yes, I received Error 500, but i did try on a normal server hosted on cpanel by providers, it works on 1.7.0.2 Do you have gmail chat, can we talk there? Would really really appreciate your help, *desperate*
I'm using bitnami magento Stack
http://answers.bitnami.org/questions/9664/smtp-issue-no-solution-making-the-magento-stack-useless

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to send Forgot Password Email from localhost.

Only thing you need to do is follow the steps listed below and your done.

1. Modify this page `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php`

Comment the existing functionality and add the below code

```
    public function getMail()
    {
     if (is_null($this->_mail)) {
        /* changes begin */
       $my_smtp_host = Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/host');
       $my_smtp_port = Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/port');
       $config = array(
                'port' => $my_smtp_port,
                'auth' => 'login',
                'username' => 'your username',
                'password' => 'your password'
            );
        $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp($my_smtp_host, $config);
        Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($transport);
        /* Changes End */
        $this->_mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');
    }
    return $this->_mail;
}
```

2. Login to admin `System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Mail Sending settings` and set the following things.

   Disable Email Communications = No

   Host = smtp.mandrillapp.com

   Port (25) = 587

   Set Return-Path = No

[image]

3. Login to admin `System -> Transactional Emails -> Add New Template` follow these steps

   - In Load default template - select the required template like `'Forgot Password'` and click on the `Load Template` a default template will be be populated in the template content
   - In Template Information - Provide any template name like `Forgot Password` and click on save template.
4. Login to admin `System -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration -> Password Options`

   - In `Forgot Email Template` select 'Forgot Password' (which was created in
     Transactional Emails tab) from the drop down.
   - Select `Remind Email Template` to 'Forgot Password'
   - Select `Forgot and Remind Email Sender` to any drop down value for ex -
     customer support.

[image]

Note - Make Sure the customer support is set to some valid email address. In order modify the customer support email - Login to admin `System -> Configuration -> General -> Store email Address -> Customer support` add the valid email address.

That's all your done. Please feel free to post your queries.
For more info refer this http://pravams.com/2011/07/30/magento-send-email-using-smtp/

Comment: the file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php didn't found at latest version of Magento but rest of the process is OK

Answer (score 2):

Magento Mail transport is set up and executed from these two functions

1. `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template -> send()`
2. `Mage_Newsletter_Model_Template -> send()`

Here's the working module code I created to direct **transactional emails** through our email service provider. It overwrites `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template -> send()`

Note that you will need to hard code the extra config items for your purposes as this code sample is missing the setup to add the fields to system config, but it should give you an idea of how the send() function needs to be changed for using an SMTP server that requires authentication and can provide SSL/TLS secured transport.

```
public function send($email, $name = null, array $variables = array())
{
    if (!$this->isValidForSend()) {
        Mage::logException(new Exception('This letter cannot be sent.')); // translation is intentionally omitted
        return false;
    }

    /* Set up mail transport to Email Hosting Provider SMTP Server via SSL/TLS */
    $config = array(
            'ssl'      => Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/ssl'),      // option of none, ssl or tls
            'port'     => Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/port'),     // TLS 587 - SSL 465 - default 25
            'auth'     => Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/auth'),     // Auth type none, login, plain, CRAM-MD5
            'username' => Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/username'),
            'password' => Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/password')
        );

    /* Set up transport package to host */
    $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp(Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/host'), $config);
    /* End transport setup */

    $emails = array_values((array)$email);
    $names = is_array($name) ? $name : (array)$name;
    $names = array_values($names);
    foreach ($emails as $key => $email) {
        if (!isset($names[$key])) {
            $names[$key] = substr($email, 0, strpos($email, '@'));
        }
    }

    $variables['email'] = reset($emails);
    $variables['name'] = reset($names);

    // ini_set('SMTP', Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/host'));
    // ini_set('smtp_port', Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/port'));

    $mail = $this->getMail();

    $setReturnPath = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SENDING_SET_RETURN_PATH);
    switch ($setReturnPath) {
        case 1:
            $returnPathEmail = $this->getSenderEmail();
            break;
        case 2:
            $returnPathEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SENDING_RETURN_PATH_EMAIL);
            break;
        default:
            $returnPathEmail = null;
            break;
    }

    if ($returnPathEmail !== null) {
        $mailTransport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail("-f".$returnPathEmail);
        Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($mailTransport);
    }

    foreach ($emails as $key => $email) {
        $mail->addTo($email, '=?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode($names[$key]) . '?=');
    }

    $this->setUseAbsoluteLinks(true);
    $text = $this->getProcessedTemplate($variables, true);

    if($this->isPlain()) {
        $mail->setBodyText($text);
    } else {
        $mail->setBodyHTML($text);
    }

    $mail->setSubject('=?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->getProcessedTemplateSubject($variables)) . '?=');
    $mail->setFrom($this->getSenderEmail(), $this->getSenderName());

    try {
        /* Send Transport, empty and log success */
        $mail->send($transport); //transport object
        $this->_mail = null;
        Mage::log('Mailed to: ' . $this->getSenderEmail() . ' ' . $this->getSenderName() . ' ' .$this->getProcessedTemplateSubject($variables), null, 'email.log');
        /* End */
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        /* Or empty and log failure */
        $this->_mail = null;
        Mage::log('Failure: ' . $e, null, 'email.log');
        Mage::logException($e);
        return false;
        /* End */
    }

    return true;
}
```